# Camera control inside an Android application

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I am building an application for Android 2.2 which is based on a photo library. There is an option to take picture from **camera** and use it in the application. I am expecting:

1. To enable the camera from the application.
2. To take the picture.
3. To automatically close the camera and show the captured picture inside the application

Unfortunately, I am not able to get the captured image to the application. Once photo is taken, camera is not closing automatically or returning to the app. Now I have to click the back button to go to the app and select the picture manually select from SD card. Camera is opening through intent and I am using the following class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: Have you use Camera class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: Are you using custom camera or opening camera through intent ??

Comment: Yes I camera is using intent and I am using the above mentioned camera class. I have updated the question with those inputs.

Comment: What's the intent that you are firing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do two things. Start the Camera app and tell it where to store the picture that it takes:

```
File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "myFile.jpg");
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
startActivityForResult(intent, myRequestCode);
```

When the user closes the Camera app, you app and Activity will be resumed. So you must override [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) to get the result:

```
if (resultCode == myRequestCode){
  File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myFile.jpg");
  // open it, show it, insert into MediaStore whatever
}
```

If you don't provide the place to save, you can alternatively retrieve it using either [intent.getData](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getData%28%29) or [intent.getParcelableExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableExtra%28java.lang.String%29) using [Intent.EXTRA_STREAM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM).

Answer (score 2):

I guess .. you are doing similar to the below code

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            // request code

```
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

using startActivityForResult instead of startActivity.. whenever you are done with your camera..  press ok.. and you will come back to your activity.. then in your activity onActivityResult callback will be called. here you will get the data for the clicked image.

Thanks.